# What are PCL-compliant equivalents of IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder methods?

Tags: c#, portable-class-library

The `System.Net.IPAddress` class is not available for PCL (Portable Class Libraries) in .NET. I am attempting to migrate some code that deals with binary streams to PCL and there is extensive use of the `NetworkToHostOrder` methods of `IPAddress` (there are three overloads). What would be equivalent PCL-compliant code?

Comment: They are *very* simple methods, just [copy them](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/IPAddress.cs,09e851fed446e0f5).

Answer (score 0):

Ended up borrowing from Mono:

```cs
internal static class EndianConverter
{
    public static long NetworkToHostOrder(long network)
    {
        return !BitConverter.IsLittleEndian ? network : SwapLong(network);
    }

    public static int NetworkToHostOrder(int network)
    {
        return !BitConverter.IsLittleEndian ? network : SwapInt(network);
    }

    public static short NetworkToHostOrder(short network)
    {
        return !BitConverter.IsLittleEndian ? network : SwapShort(network);
    }

    public static short HostToNetworkOrder(short host)
    {
        return !BitConverter.IsLittleEndian ? (host) : SwapShort(host);
    }

    public static int HostToNetworkOrder(int host)
    {
        return !BitConverter.IsLittleEndian ? (host) : SwapInt(host);
    }

    public static long HostToNetworkOrder(long host)
    {
        return !BitConverter.IsLittleEndian ? (host) : SwapLong(host);
    }

    private static short SwapShort(short number)
    {
        return (short) (((number >> 8) & 0xFF) | ((number << 8) & 0xFF00));
    }

    private static int SwapInt(int number)
    {
        return (((number >> 24) & 0xFF)
        | ((number >> 08) & 0xFF00)
        | ((number << 08) & 0xFF0000)
        | ((number << 24)));
    }

    private static long SwapLong(long number)
    {
        return (((number >> 56) & 0xFF)
        | ((number >> 40) & 0xFF00)
        | ((number >> 24) & 0xFF0000)
        | ((number >> 08) & 0xFF000000)
        | ((number << 08) & 0xFF00000000)
        | ((number << 24) & 0xFF0000000000)
        | ((number << 40) & 0xFF000000000000)
        | ((number << 56)));
    }
```